# Clojure flexible function design based on arguments?

Tags: clojure

I have functions that behave different depending on which keyword arguments have values supplied. For this question, I am wondering about functions that behave slightly differently depending on the type of argument supplied.

Example function, that increments each element of a list:

```
(defn inc-list [& {:keys [list-str list]}]
  (let [prepared-list (if-not (nil? list) list (clojure.string/split list-str #","))]
    (map inc prepared-list)))
```

Does it make sense to make a multimethod that instead tests for the type of argument? I have not used multimethods before, not sure about right time to use them. If it is a good idea, would the below example make sense?

Example:

```
(defn inc-coll [col] (map inc col))
(defmulti inc-list class)
(defmethod inc-list ::collection [col] (inc-col col))
(defmethod inc-list String [list-str] 
  (inc-col 
    (map #(Integer/parseInt %)
         (clojure.string/split list-str #",")))
```

Answer (score 5):

First things first: `(map 'inc x)` treats each item in `x` as an associative collection, and looks up the value indexed by the key `'inc`.

```
user> (map 'inc '[{inc 0} {inc 1} {inc 2}])
(0 1 2)
```

you probably want `inc` instead

```
user> (map inc [0 1 2])
(1 2 3)
```

Next, we have an attempt to `inc` a string, the args to `string/split` out of order, and some spelling errors.

If you define your multi to dispatch on `class`, then the methods should be parameterized by the Class, not a keyword placeholder. I changed the multi so it would work on anything Clojure knows how to treat as a seq. Also, as a bit of bikeshedding, it is better to use `type`, which offers some distinctions for differentiating inputs in Clojure code that `class` does not offer:

```
user> (type (with-meta  {:a 0 :b 1} {:type "foo"}))
"foo"
```

Putting it all together:

```
user> (defn inc-coll [col] (map inc col))
#'user/inc-coll
user> (defmulti inc-list type) 
nil
user> (defmethod inc-list String [list-str]
        (inc-coll (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (clojure.string/split list-str #","))))
#<MultiFn clojure.lang.MultiFn@6507d1de>
user> (inc-list "1,10,11")
(2 11 12)
user> (defmethod inc-list clojure.lang.Seqable [col] (inc-coll (seq col)))
#<MultiFn clojure.lang.MultiFn@6507d1de>
user> (inc-list [1 2 3])
(2 3 4)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely informative. I edited my post for the errors you found, thanks again. The type metadata wasn't something I considered, I'm not familiar with it. Just one more thing, does using a multimethod make sense for this application? What are the pros and cons of doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is an obfuscated application of a technique called dispatching on type. It is obfuscated because in a message-passing style the caller must convey the type to your function.

Since in every case you only use one of the keyword args, you could as well define it as:

```
(defn inc-list
  [m l]
  (->> (case m   ;; message dispatch
         :list l
         :list-str (map #(edn/read-string %) (str/split #",")) l)
       (map inc)))
```

The caller could be relieved from having to pass m:

```
(defn inc-list
  [l]
  (->> (cond (string? l) (map ...)
             :else l)
       (map inc)))
```

This technique has the main disadvantage that the operation procedure code must be modified when a new type is introduced to the codebase.

In Clojure it is generally superseeded by the polymorphism construct [protocols](http://clojure.org/protocols), e. g.:

```
(defprotocol IncableList
   (inc-list [this]))
```

Can be implemented on any type, e. g.

```
(extend-type clojure.lang.Seqable
   IncableList
   (inc-list [this] (map inc this)))

(extend-type String
   IncableList
   (inc-list [this] (map #(inc ...) this)))
```

[Multimethods](http://clojure.org/multimethods) allow the same and provide additional flexibility over message-passing *and* dispatching on type by decoupling the dispatch mechanism from the operation procedures and providing the additivity of data-directed programming. They perform slower than protocols, though.

In your example the intention is to dispatch based on type, so you don't need multimethods and protocols are the appropriate technique.